# Find minimal wire connection

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

### The problem

You are given a board of size **a** by **a**. There're **n** components on the board, which have to be connected to the edges of the board with minimal length of wires possible.
Wires are straight and can't overlap.

Find the algorithm to do connect the components to the edges with these constraints.

**Contstraints are**:

time: 1s 
space: infinity
1 <= a <= 30
1 <= n <= 38

**Example:**

```
Input:
4
3
2 1
2 3
3 3

Output:
5
DOWN
UP
UP
```

[image]

---

### What I've already tried

I found a kind of recursion, let me show the idea with data provided above.

I have a n-bit mask, where `1` on i-th position represents, that we take this component into account, while `0` not.

When I start recursion I have n ones:

```
           111
     /      |     \
   /        |      \
  011      101     110
 /   \    /  \    /   \
001 010  001 100 010 100
```

When I came to the lowest level, I have exactly one `1`. I find optimal solution (shortest way) for this simple problem and then I just use it for further computations.

However, I have a problem, that this optimal solution may lead to overlapping.

Comment: Can you please explain the input and output format? (What is that 5). Are you sure that there will always be solution? How this recursion tree tells you the solution exactly?

Comment: We receive **a**, which is the size of the square board, in the first line. Then we get **n**, which is the amount of components. After that we input n lines of coordinates of the contacts on the board.
The output means the following:
5 - minimal total length of the wires possible
And then the direction of wire going for i-th component.
Yes, there could be a situation, when there will be no solution, but the input is guaranteed to be correct and solvable.

Comment: This recursion tree represents the states of my dp. 001 means, that I ignore components #1 and #2 and find the minimal possible solution just for the component #3. Then I traverse it to the top and look at the situation, when I have just 2 components, e.g. 011 - I ignore component #1 and look at minimal possible solution for components #2 and #3 together

Comment: Ok! Things are more clear now. I still don't understand why there are 5 wires and not 3 for minimal solution.

Comment: Can more than one component be connected to a single wire? Can wires go left or right in addition to up or down?

Comment: Oh, woops, I just thought about another number and wrote 5. Of course 3!

Comment: The wires can go LEFT UP DOWN AND RIGHT, but a single wire should go only through one component

Comment: We'd have a much better grasp of your difficulties if you'd post an example *without* a trivial solution.  Also note that some configurations do not *have* a solution; what should the algorithm do in such a case?

Comment: Why is there a numeral in the output at all?  The quantity of wires, by problem definition, is exactly the quantity of components.

Comment: @Prune output is total length of rather than number of wires.

Comment: @Prune as I wrote above, there will be no incorrect input

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  I didn't notice the "correct and solvable" because it's not in the problem statement.  We generally need any substantive clarifications to be in the posting, not relegated to comments alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I can't really see something better or more clever than a [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) approach to solve that. It is somehow similar to what you have proposed, but does not have redundant calculations.
Here it is briefly described as a pythonic pseudocode:

```
def BnB(grid, components):
    queue = new_priority_queue()  # classic priority queue
    empty_sol = [None for i in range(len(components))]  # we create an 'empty' solution
    queue.push((0, 0, empty_sol))  # we push an initial empty solution on the queue (a tuple total len, index, solution)
    best_length_so_far = infinite # we keep track of the best solution seen so far
    best_sol_so_far = None
    while not queue.is_empty():
        length, index, solution = queue.pop()
        if index == len(components):  # it is a feasible solution
            if best_len_so_far > length:
                best_len_so_far = length
                best_sol_so_far = solution
        elif length < best_len_so_far:
           #  check if components[index] can have its wire 'DOWN'
           if can_put_wire(grid, components, index, 'DOWN'):
               length_to_add = path_len(grid, component, index, 'DOWN')
               new_sol = copy(solution)
               new_sol[index] = 'DOWN'
               queue.push((length + length_to_add, index + 1, new_sol))
           # do the same thing for the other directions
           if can_put_wire(grid, components, index, 'UP'):
               ....
           if can_put_wire(grid, components, index, 'LEFT'):
               ....
           if can_put_wire(grid, components, index, 'RIGHT'):
               ....
return best_sol_so_far
```

The exploration of the solutions tree would depend on how you set the priorities on your queue. The choice of the component to consider (rather than to take them in the order like in the code above) could also help to have solutions faster.
This will not be efficient (complexity in time exponential w.r.t the number of components), but it can find the solution.

Another possibility is to use [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (integer linear programming) to solve the problem. It can be rather easily described with linear constraints, and would enjoy all the optimizations offered by a LP solver.

Comment: I guess branch and bounds method won't always give the best solution. It will be close to optimal, but not the optimal one

Comment: Please supply some educational counter-examples.

Comment: Ok, given the following input:
`14\n
3
1 8
3 10
2 8`
It will output:
`12
LEFT
LEFT
DOWN`
But the correct output is:
`11
LEFT
UP
UP`
This will happen, because of the order of components traversal. It will mark the solution, where you have to make "bad direction" on the second point as bad, and thus will connect 2nd component to the closest edge, which is the left one. Although this solution is good enough, it's not the optimal one. Just draw the picture to understand

Comment: My mistake, I guess, this one is the solution

Comment: Yes, branch and bound is an exact method which rovides an optimal answer.  The way I see it, it is just an improvement of a purely recursive (or backtracking) approach, where some branches of the tree are being pruned if they do not have any chance to carry one optimal solution leaf.